# 2D game ImageIO import issue

Tags: java, eclipse, javax.imageio

I am making a 2d game based on minecraft.  The code below worked on my pc but not my mac.  The image I am trying to load is in the Background folder inside the Resources folder.  Other posts I have read suggest the error is because my image couldn't be found but I don't know what else to put for the image location.

here is my code:

```
public MenuState(GameStateManager gsm) {

    super(gsm);

    try {

        // load minecraft Background
        minecraft = ImageIO.read(
            getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Backgrounds/minecraft.png ")
                ).getSubimage(0, 300, 400, 300);

        // load floating head
        head = ImageIO.read(
            getClass().getResourceAsStream("/HUD/Hud.gif")
        ).getSubimage(0, 12, 12, 11);
```

Error Message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1348)
at GameState.MenuState.<init>(MenuState.java:50)
at GameState.GameStateManager.loadState(GameStateManager.java:40)
at GameState.GameStateManager.<init>(GameStateManager.java:34)
at Creeper.GamePanel.init(GamePanel.java:71)
at Creeper.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:76)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is not a problem of ImageIO. It is a problem of finding the resource. Isolate `getResourceAsStream()` and edit it until it returns something != null

Comment: Is there a way to find out the images location?  I've been trying different locations all day and it always comes out null

Comment: Your image must be in the classpath. If you are using maven, then place it in src/main/resources.

Comment: Include the Resources folder to your classpath